# How do I create a Facebook Share button using ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to implement a Facebook Share button using ASP.NET MVC3, like following image.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlJwd.png]

I have installed Microsoft Web Helper in my MVC application, and  I am able to create a Facebook Like button using `@Facebook.LikeButton();`; But how can I create a Facebook Share button?

Answer (score 1):

The Share Button is [no longer officially supported](http://barbariangroup.com/posts/7544-the_facebook_share_button_has_been_deprecated_called_it) by Facebook.  However, for now you can still achieve the old Share Button's functionality by using Facebook's "sharer.php" app.

Just apply a link in the following format to your button image or link text:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yourpage.com
```

In the long run though, your safer solution would be to use one of the still supported [social plugins](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/), like the "Like" button or the ["Send" button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/).

Answer (score 0):

The facebook share button isn't available in the facebook helper, only the following social plugins:

- Like Button
- Activity Feed
- Recommendations
- Like Box
- Login Button
- Facepile
- Comments
- Live Stream

http://facebookhelper.codeplex.com/documentation

By the way the share button is deprecated and will be not supported in the future, because the click through rates of the Like Button are better. More info at the bottom of this page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/